# regex php separate an exact word from string in diffrent groups

Tags: php, regex, cpu-word

i have tried all i know but still can't figure out how to resolve this problem :

i have a string ex :

- `"--included-- in selling price: 5 % vat usd 10.00 packaging fees 2 % notifying fees"`
- `"--not included-- in selling price: us$ 35.00 express fees 2 % notifying fees"`

i want to know if the taxes are "included" or "excluded" and if the fees are "%" or "currency" 
the problem is it doesn't detect the currency "usd" while it's attached to the taxe name "vat usd"

how can i separate the currency from the name of the taxe in different groups.

**here is what i did**

```
(--excluded--|--included--|--not included--)([a-z ]*)?:?(usd | aed | mad | € | us\$ )?([ \. 0-9 ]*)(%)?([a-z A-z ?]*) (aed|mad|€|us\$)*((aed|mad|€|us\$)+)?([\. 0-9 ]*)(%)?([a-z A-z]*)(.*)?
```

**and here is what i got**

```
Match 1
Full match  0-83    --included-- in selling price: 5 % vat usd 10.00 packaging fees 2 % notifying fees

Group 1.    0-12    --included--

Group 2.    12-29    in selling price

Group 4.    30-33    5 

Group 5.    33-34   %

Group 6.    34-42    vat usd

Group 10.   43-49   10.00 

Group 12.   49-64   packaging fees 

Group 13.   64-82   2 % notifying fees
```

**and here is what i want**

```
Match 1
Full match  0-83    --included-- in selling price: 5 % vat usd 10.00 packaging fees 2 % notifying fees

Group 1.    0-12    --included--

Group 2.    12-29    in selling price

Group 4.    30-33    5 

Group 5.    33-34   %

Group 6.    34-38    vat

Group 7.    38-42    usd

Group 10.   43-49   10.00 

Group 12.   49-64   packaging fees 

Group 13.   64-82   2 % notifying fees
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
$s = "--included-- in product price: breakfast --excluded--: 5 % vat aed 10.00 destination fee per night 2 % municipality fee 3.5 % packaging fee 10 % warranty service charge";
$results = [];
if (preg_match_all('~(--(?:(?:not )?in|ex)cluded--)(?:\s+([a-zA-Z ]+))?:+\s*((?:(?!--(?:(?:not )?in|ex)cluded--).)*)~su', $s, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)) {
    foreach ($m as $v) {
        $lastline=array_pop($v); // Remove last item //print_r($details);
        if (preg_match_all('~(?:(\b(?:usd|aed|mad|usd)\b|\B€|\bus\$)\s*)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:(?!(?1))\D)*~ui', $lastline, $details)) {
            $results[] = array_merge($v, $details[0]);
        } else {
            $results[] = $v;
        }
    }
}
print_r($results);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/3PJ9J).

*Notes*:

The first regex extracts each match you need to parse. See [the first regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nh80dU/1). It means:

- `(--(?:(?:not )?in|ex)cluded--)` - Group 1: a shorter version of `(--excluded--|--included--|--not included--)`: `--excluded--`, `--included--` or `--not included--`
- `(?:\s+([a-zA-Z ]+))?` - an optional sequence: 1+ whitespaces and then Group 2: 1+ ASCII letters or spaces
- `:+` - 1 or more colons
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `((?:(?!--(?:(?:not )?in|ex)cluded--).)*)` - Group 3: any char, 0+ occurrences, as many as possible, not starting any of the three char sequences: `--excluded--`, `--included--`, `--not included--`

Then, the Group 3 value needs to be further parsed to grab all the details. [The second regex](https://regex101.com/r/5qJt3N/1) is used here to match

- `(?:(\b(?:usd|aed|mad|usd)\b|\B€|\bus\$)\s*)?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `(\b(?:usd|aed|mad|usd)\b|\B€|\bus\$)` - Group 1:

    - `\b(?:usd|aed|mad|usd)\b` - `usd`, `aed`, `mad` or `usd` as whole words
    - `\B€` - `€` not preceded with a word char
    - `\bus\$` - `us$` not preceded with a word char
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\d+`
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional sequence of `.` and 1+ digits
- `(?:(?!(?1))\D)*` - any non-digit char, 0 or more occurrences, as many as possible, not starting the same pattern as in Group 1

Comment: Hi Wiktor,
it worked for the first example but not this one
ex : "--not included-- in selling price: us$ 35.00 express fees usd 15.00 notifying fees
"
here is what i got : 

Group 4. 212-218 35.00 
Group 10. 218-218 
Group 12. 218-235 express fees usd

Comment: @MounirMoel What do you mean? Please explain each part you need to capture and why if you want more help. I posted all possible hints for you to further fine tune the regex if you prefer to keep the requirements to yourself.

Comment: yes i do 
i need to capture the amount only in a group and the currency  only in an other group
and when i do the soltion you gaev me, it capture " express fees usd" in one group 
and i need two separate groupe one to capture " express fees" and an other one to capture  "usd" 
i hope you understand the need now :)

Comment: @MounirMoel So, that means, you need to add another capturing group before the last one, right?

Comment: Try [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/mJPFk6/1), see [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/iGjLL). If it is what you need, I will work on it a bit more since it is a bit imprecise now.

Comment: yes but i need also to know "notifying fees" so the last part is not captured in your example, and i have also added a new example that didn't work (it's the last one)  https://regex101.com/r/0TKXaj/3
thank you for your help :)

Comment: Hi wiktor,
your help is very apreciated,  in the 4th example "destination fee per night" is supposed to be just one group and "vat 2 % other fees 3.5 % express fee 10 % service charge" is supposed to be devided in 10 groups 
can you check and let me know please :)

Comment: hi Wiktor 
any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Hi Wiktor i really need your help :)

Comment: @MounirMoel It is impossible to adjust the regex without knowing the requirements. List them all in the question, explain what should appear in which group and why.

Comment: Hi wiktor,
Here are the examples https://regex101.com/r/VixM23/1
i need to know exactly in each example what are the fees and taxes to pay. 
i need every "(tax or fee) Name" and the amount.
just like the first line of the example i gave you.
the numbre of taxes in each line may vary.
i hope it's clear now :)

Comment: @MounirMoel What about a solution including a bit more PHP code? See [this demo](https://3v4l.org/ho7on). I assumed there is always `:` after `--...---`.

Comment: @MounirMoel See [the updated code with fixed number matching](https://3v4l.org/LXWBM). You may further enhance the code to get more details out of the matches.

Comment: Stribizew it's ok for me to use php code and the solution may work but i have just one problem 
<pre>
in the result 

[3] => 5 % vat aed 
[4] => 10.00 destination fee per night

it should be

[3] => 5 % vat 
[4] => aed  10.00 destination fee per night
</pre>

Comment: Hi Wiktor your solution is perfect for me thank you very much for your help  :)